# while updating app from playstore i am getting the error "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper"

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, app-update

while updating app from playstore I'm getting the error..

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available 09-02 17:10:03.586 11866-12008/? W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper 09-02 17:10:03.586 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 09-02 17:10:03.587 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324) 09-02 17:10:03.587 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285) 09-02 17:10:03.587 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.ZeroBalanceHelperClass.getFeatureFlagValue(ZeroBalanceHelperClass.java:39)
09-02 17:10:03.587 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.followUpRequest(HttpEngine.java:1090)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:393)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
 com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:501)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
 com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
 com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at la.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:193) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at lb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:151) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at jt.c(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:608) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at lm.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:242) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 09-02 17:10:03.588 11866-12008/? W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.net.ZeroBalanceHelper 09-02 17:10:03.592 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 09-02 17:10:03.592 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 09-02 17:10:03.592 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 09-02 17:10:03.592 11866-12008/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 09-02 17:10:03.592 11866-12008/? W/System.err:  ... 18 more
```

app doesn't run after this error, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this coming from your own device?

Comment: can you paste some of your code?

Comment: Error logs says that error is from server side but i think it is generating from your device !

Comment: yes its generated from my own device

Comment: So while executing(run your app and building apk) at this time error generating? or after update app to play store and download updated apk gives you error ?

Comment: after I update the app from play store and download updated apk gives me error

Comment: Ok so when you release your apk file , test it before upload  to play store and check that apk gives same error ?

Comment: Currently I am testing using release build variant on the previous version of playstore apk . (This error is generating at alpha testing the app)

Comment: @AnushkaKhare Oh Okay !! Np. Will solve ur issue. You can drop me a test mail getting my id from SO profile. I will look into it !!